# How to have an anchor tag linking to part of the page alongside base_url?

Tags: html, anchor

I have a site that for various reasons (mobile browser consistency mostly) needs the `<base href="/">` tag in the `<head>`.

The only problem is this has affected anchor tags that redirect to other sections of the same page, eg:

```
<a href="#section2">Section 2</a>
```

With the base href tag these now all redirect back to the root home page.

Apart from coming through and making each of these anchor tags absolute or replacing them with a JS solution, is there a way to fix this?